# http post problems in Android 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: android, http-post, android-5.0-lollipop

I am having a problem with Android 5.0. The application downloads information from my server using `HttpPost`. It works perfectly in any Android version but it is not working in Android 5.0.

Here is the logcat::

```
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
    03-18 16:06:26.141: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:442)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:476)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at es.company.name.remote.ProductoClient.getPorFiltros(ProductoClient.java:146)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at es.company.name.asyncTasks.ProductosPorFiltrosAsyncTask.doInBackground(ProductosPorFiltrosAsyncTask.java:69)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at es.company.name.asyncTasks.ProductosPorFiltrosAsyncTask.doInBackground(ProductosPorFiltrosAsyncTask.java:1)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    03-18 16:06:26.142: W/System.err(19565):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is part of my code:

(CobrosClient.java)

```
    public static final List<Cobros> getPorId(final  Context ctx) throws Exception {

    List<Cobros> lst=new ArrayList<Cobros>();

    final String servletUrl = "https://" + Constants.SERVER_URL + ":"  + Constants.SERVER_PORT + "/" + SERVLET_COBROS_URL;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

    try {
        httpClient = HttpClientUtils.getHttpClient(ctx, Constants.SERVER_PORT);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(servletUrl);
        ServletParameters sp = new ServletParameters(GangaPreferencesStore.getUserName(ctx), "getPorId");
        sp.put("idComerciante",  GangaPreferencesStore.getUserName(ctx));
        httpPost.setEntity(sp.toEntity());
        HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine=httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() != 200){
            throw new Exception("Error en CobrosClient.getPorId(...): statusCode="+statusLine.getStatusCode()+", "+statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }else{
            //care
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8"));
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                lst.add(Cobros.fromJSONObject(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.error(CobrosClient.class, e);
        throw e;
    }finally {
        try{
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    return lst;
}
```

(HttpClientsUtils)

```
    public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient (Context context, String serverPort) throws   NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                                                                                            CertificateException, 
                                                                                            IOException, 
                                                                                            KeyStoreException, 
                                                                                            KeyManagementException, 
                                                                                            UnrecoverableKeyException {
    KeyStore keyStoreBouncyCastle = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.elaboro_keystore_bks);
    try {
        keyStoreBouncyCastle.load(in, "orobale".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory=new SSLSocketFactory(keyStoreBouncyCastle);
    sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, Integer.parseInt(serverPort)));

    final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(        httpParams, Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);

    DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(new SingleClientConnManager(httpParams, registry), httpParams);
    defaultHttpClient.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultHttpRoutePlanner(registry));
    return defaultHttpClient;
}
```

(Cobros.java)

```
    public static Cobros fromJSONObject(JSONObject jo) throws JSONException {

    Cobros c = new Cobros();

    c.idComerciante             = jo.getString("idComerciante");
    c.tipoPago                  = jo.getInt("tipoPago");
    c.fechaAltaSuscripcion      = jo.getString("fechaAltaSuscripcion");
    c.errorPago                 = jo.getInt("errorPago");
    c.activo                    = jo.getInt("activo");

    return c;
}
```

I have tried many things that I have found in other questions but still does not work. I want to repeat again that it works in any version except 5.0. Can anybody give me a hint? I would appreciate it so much. Thanxs in advance.

Comment: FWIW, a `POST` should not be used to "download information." That's what `GET` is for. Regardless... do you have internet connectivity?

Comment: It is not intenet connectivity problem, I am trying with differents moviles at the same place, same WiFi. It works for all of them except lollipop

Comment: That's nice, but *have you verified* that wifi is working on the lollipop device?

Comment: What is the connection type you are using? share your code

Comment: A tcpdump/wireshark dump might be useful when debugging something like that. Both for working and not-working case.

Comment: Did you find any fix?